# TSC printer not printing .BMP files

Tags: android, printing, barcode, tsc, thermal-printer

## Printer model tdm-20.

I need to print bmp file,
my code  is:

```
        `macAddress = mBTDevices[position].address
         TscDll.openport(macAddress)
         TscDll.setup(100, 60, 1, 15, 0, 3, 0)

        TscDll.clearbuffer()
        TscDll.downloadbmp("test.bmp")

        TscDll.printlabel(1, 1)

        TscDll.closeport(5000)`
```

and its not worked.
Printer print a clear staff.
I use galaxy note 9 with Android 10.
If i send text its works fine.

Comment: It seems that the description such as `TscDll.sendcommand("PUTBMP 100,520,\"Test.bmp\"\n");` is required. [Instruction for Android SDK](https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/DownloadFile/DownloadFileSupport/1163/file?m_id=5953&ReturnUrl=support%2Fsupport_download%2FTDM-20)

Answer (score 0):

```
TscEthernetDll.setup(100, 150, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0);
TscEthernetDll.clearbuffer();
TscEthernetDll.sendpicture(0,20,path);
TscEthernetDll.sendcommand("PUTBMP 100,520,\""+path+"\"\r\n");
Thread.sleep(1000);
TscEthernetDll.sendcommand("PRINT 1\r\n");
```